# DateTimePicker contabilizar e marcar os próximos dias úteis

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, data, calendario

Bom dia!

Estou com um grande problema, utilizo o Bootstrap DateTimePicker para incluir um calendário logo acima de um cronômetro em uma página html, porém agora, foi solicitado que neste calendário, os próximos 5 dias úteis posteriores ao dia atual fossem demarcados para que seja passado com exatidão a data correta ao cliente que entrou em contato conosco.

Estou iniciando ainda em desenvolvimento java e, relacionado a php não tenho conhecimentos suficientes, fora também o fato do servidor que utilizo para upload de arquivos funcionar como uma intranet, onde esta barrando qualquer tipo de exibição/retorno referente a arquivos em PHP.

o código que estou utilizando no datetimepicker é o seguinte:

```
   /* Calendário com Feriados Nacionais */
    $(function () {
            $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({
                locale: 'pt-br',
                format:'L',
                daysOfWeekDisabled: [0, 6],
                disabledDates: [ 
                    "1/1/2018",
                    "2/12/2018",
                    "2/13/2018",
                    "3/30/2018",
                    "4/21/2018",
                    "5/1/2018",
                    "5/31/2018",
                    "9/7/2018",
                    "10/12/2018",
                    "11/2/2018",
                    "11/15/2018",
                    "12/25/2018",

                    "1/1/2019",
                    "3/4/2019",
                    "3/5/2019",
                    "4/14/2019",
                    "4/21/2019",
                    "5/1/2019",
                    "6/20/2019",
                    "9/7/2019",
                    "10/12/2019",
                    "11/2/2019",
                    "11/15/2019",
                    "12/25/2019",                        

                    "1/1/2020",
                    "2/24/2020",
                    "2/25/2020",
                    "4/10/2020",
                    "4/21/2020",
                    "5/1/2020",
                    "6/11/2020",
                    "9/7/2020",
                    "10/12/2020",
                    "11/2/2020",
                    "11/15/2020",
                    "12/25/2020",   

                    "1/1/2021",
                    "2/15/2021",
                    "2/16/2021",
                    "4/2/2021",
                    "4/21/2021",
                    "5/1/2021",
                    "6/3/2021",
                    "9/7/2021",
                    "10/12/2021",
                    "11/2/2021",
                    "11/15/2021",
                    "12/25/2021",     

                    "1/1/2022",
                    "2/28/2022",
                    "2/29/2022",
                    "4/15/2022",
                    "4/21/2022",
                    "5/1/2022",
                    "6//2022",
                    "9/7/2022",
                    "10/12/2022",
                    "11/2/2022",
                    "11/15/2022",
                    "12/25/2022",                          

                ],



            });
        });
```

Alguém saberia me dizer se é possível efetuar essa inclusão dos 5 dias úteis que estão habilitados posteriores a data atual utilizando este plugin ou seria necessário trabalhar com outro em especifico?

Caso seja necessário a utilização de um outro plugin em especifico qual seria?

Muito obrigado pela atenção

Comment: não entendi muito bem, você quer desabilitar os feriados? no futuro?

Comment: Não não, eu quero que a partir do dia atual, sejam contabilizados 5 dias úteis, exemplo:

acionei o calendario hoje, dia 04/07 quarta feira, precisaria que os dias 05,06,09,10 e 11 estivessem demarcados saca?